# In mysql, how to dynamically create a view based on different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view

Maybe it's not so clear to understand by reading the title. I'm new to mysql, now I have a table named on everyday's date, so everyday the table's name is different.

For example, table now:

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_mydb |
+----------------+
| mytab_20120922 |
+----------------+
```

Now I create a view which is used to select all from today's table(mytab_20120922):

```
mysql> create view myview as (select * from mytab_20120922);
```

Tommorow, the table's name will be different:

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_mydb |
+----------------+
| mytab_20120923 |
+----------------+
```

then it will be wrong to use `myview` to see all datas in mytab_20120923. Is there any good idea to solve this problem?

Comment: It is wrong design to have more than one table with the same structure. Add the 'xxxx' as a column to the original table, store all the data in one table and create your view using a WHERE condition.

Comment: @AlexMonthy `xxxxx` here means they are same strings between tables, maybe I should change `xxxxx` to a more specific name :)

Comment: Agree with Alex that it's not a right design. Will you be fine with a stored procedure instead? If so, you can construct the SELECT statement dynamically as a string and `exec` it.

Comment: @AlexMonthy Eh..Maybe you are right, I am thinking about a better design..

Answer (score 0):

Aldo I think that this is a bed design and that design should be changed as suggested in the comments, if you really want to do this, it is possible using [MySql Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) by creating a [Stored Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) which dynamically creates a select from a today's table and executes it, and then selecting from that Stored Procedure.